# RESTKit response.url changed order of parameters

Tags: ios, api, restkit

I'm using RESTKit to get data from a rest-api.

This is the URL i set for my request, here's the log just before the request goes off.

```
2014-04-03 15:51:10.186 xxx[35745:60b] Just sent URL: /api/dspObjGetNewsList?action=coverage&count=30&start=0&open=0&user=xxx&unique=36027&type=all&country=Sweden,global&division=Strategic Industries,Regional Sales and Service,Automotive
```

Then i log the reponse URL.

```
- (void)request:(RKRequest*)request didLoadResponse:(RKResponse*)response {
    NSLog(@"xxx: %d, url: %@", [response statusCode], response.URL);
```

And i get this?

```
xxx: response code: 200, url: url/api/dspObjGetNewsList?unique=26791&type=all&division=Strategic%20Industries%2CRegional%20Sales%20and%20Service%2CAutomotive&user=xxx&action=coverage&open=0&country=Sweden%2Cglobal&count=30&start=0
```

Why am i getting a different URL in my response? Does RESTKit modify my url?

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured HTTPClient properly? Use `- (id)initWithHTTPClient:(AFHTTPClient *)client` method to configure HTTPClient. For instance:

```
AFHTTPClient *HTTPClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.url.com"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first log appears to be a raw string of the URL. The second log appears to be the % escaped URL version of that string. This isn't a RestKit thing, it's a URL loading system thing. Certain characters need to be escaped so that they are valid for use in a URL.

For example, your original string has a number of spaces in it. This isn't allowed in a URL and each must be changed to `%20`.

Why the parameters change order isn't clear - it depends on how you created the string and supplied the parameters to RestKit. But, the order doesn't matter to the processing so you shouldn't need to worry about it.